# Python Function return nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing my assignment rn and there are some problems showed up, I want to return true or false in my function, but It shows nothing at the end.

```
import math
import decimal

#1
def pythagorean_pair():
    a = input("Type a number A(Must be an integer): ")
    if a.isdigit():
        a=int(a)
        b = input("Type a number B(Must be an integer): ")
        if b.isdigit():
            b = int(b)
            c = a**2 + b**2
            ans = c**(1/2)
            ans = ans - int(ans)
            if ans == 0:
                return (True)
                print ("True, they are pythagorean pair!")
            else:
                return (False)
                print ("False, they are not pythagorean pair!")
        else:
            print ("Please input an integer!!")
    else:
        print ("Please input an integer!!")
pythagorean_pair()
```

Comment: Are you intending to see something printed? You're returning before you're printing, so the printing will never happen. Please clarify what you're expecting to happen and how this code is being run.

Comment: Yes, I want to return True, if I delete the print after the return, it still doesn't show ip

Comment: Returning and printing aren't the same thing. If you aren't printing the return of `pythagorean_pair`, nothing will show up. Returning doesn't cause anything to be printed.

Comment: what if I want to return true,  and It will show a True after the function runs

Comment: Change the call to `print(pythagorean_pair())`. You need to manually print the return value.

Comment: Thank you, it works!!!!

Comment: You have `print()` calls after `return()` in a couple of places. Because of this, your function will never reach the point where it prints, because it already finished and returned.

Comment: You only return True or False if both `a` and `b` are digits. Otherwise, you return `None` (implicitly, because there are no `return` statements in those cases).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function, and as others said, if you want to print something, make sure to print it before the return. Because what *return* does is simply return the output and get out of the function call (what I mean is: nothing below *return* will run). You could do something like the following to test your code:

```
def test(a):
    if a:
        return True
    return False

a = None
if test(a):
    print("True, input is not null")
else:
    print("False, input is null!")
```

returns:

```
False, input is null!
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the function's output for an input to some code not shown in your example

e.g.,

```
boolean_value = pythagorean_pair()
```

there is no rule that you have to have a return statement. In other words, you can simply have the function print your strings, and you are done.

```
def check_answer(boolean_answer):
    print("The answer is", boolean_answer)

check_answer(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are something return,you have to `print()` it.

```
print(pythagorean_pair())
```

you appear to ask ***Why function print out nothing except `Ture/False`***.Because you return before you print,the function finished when you return . So `print()` will not execute.

Change to:

```
if ans == 0:
    print ("True, they are pythagorean pair!")
    return (True)
else:       
    print ("False, they are not pythagorean pair!")
    return (False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right just a minor tweek by using print function before the return will solve the issue. Here's your code...

#1

```
def pythagorean_pair():
    a = input("Type a number A(Must be an integer): ")
    if a.isdigit():
        a=int(a)
        b = input("Type a number B(Must be an integer): ")
        if b.isdigit():
            b = int(b)
            c = a**2 + b**2
            ans = c**(1/2)
            ans = ans - int(ans)
            if ans == 0:
                print ("True, they are pythagorean pair!")
                return (True)
                
            else:
                print ("False, they are not pythagorean pair!")
                return (False)
                
        else:
            print ("Please input an integer!!")
    else:
        print ("Please input an integer!!")
pythagorean_pair()
```